# Node.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am connecting Node.js to Android App.
And when I run 'npm start' the error(TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined) occurs.

It seems like it doesn't receive 'rows' property(the number of rows) from MySQL.

```js
router.get('/:phone', function(req, res, next){
    var phone = req.params.phone;
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM bestfood_member WHERE phone = ? LIMIT 1;";

    console.log("sql : "+ sql);

    db.get().query(sql, phone, function (err, rows){
        console.log("rows : " + JSON.stringify(rows));
        console.log("row.length : " + rows.length);

        if(rows.length > 0){
            res.json(rows[0]);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    });
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try putting `phone` in an array instead.. `db.get().query(sql, [phone], function (err, rows){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query probably errored. You need to check if the query was successfully executed.

`if (err) throw err;`

Comment: Did you check that `rows` is an array?

Comment: It says undefined.

Comment: Is `err` undefined too?

Comment: problem solved. It was a connection problem with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may use these lines of code. rowCount will tell you how many rows do you have. I have also find out this solution after couple of days.

```
db.get().query(sql, phone, function (err, rows){
        console.log("rows : " + JSON.stringify(rows));
        console.log("rows.rowCount : " + rows.rowCount);
```